# Preventing div from new string with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with some image `div` in it.

```
<div class="sliderscrollbar">
    <div class="scrollableimage"></div>
    <div class="scrollableimage"></div>
    <div class="scrollableimage"></div>
    <div class="scrollableimage"></div>
    <div class="scrollableimage"></div>
    <div class="scrollableimage"></div>
</div>

div.sliderscrollbar
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 900px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: scroll; 
}
div.scrollableimage
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    background: url('http://www.selectism.com/files/2014/12/Holiday-Gift-Guide-Stocking-Stuffers-feature-200x120.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/575ora3r/) 
The problem is that divs that doesn't suit it's width, move to next line. However I expect them to be in 1 line because they are `inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the almighty `white-space: nowrap` statement for your container element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/575ora3r/1/

Comment: great, I'll accept answer as soon as site allow it to me.